# IntelliJ CE does not recognise Play framework

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

I have an play application, IntelliJ CE does not recognise anything play.*

such as:
Error:not found: object play
import play.api.GlobalSettings

How can I fix this?

It is a gradle project and building fine from command-line but intelliJ CE has some problem with the code.

Comment: Did you import it as a Gradle project? Did you try Clean/Build in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play framework is [supported only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Answer (score 0):

Three ways you can deal with this (assuming your IntellJ is up to date):

1. Close the IntellJ and import the project again as a Gradle project.
2. Remove the `.idea` folder within the project's folder; and try to import it again.
3. Click to `Invalid Caches / Restart` from the `file` menu.